# Laravel Left join multiple tables and return the original table value

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm having issues with joining three tables and getting the original table value back.

I have a parent table which is a store that needs to find the brand_id for the products within the store. I can't access the brand_id directly so I need to join, I have to join on to the stores product list then join that onto the product table which holds the `brand_id`.

```
$this_return = Store::with('address','setting')
                    ->leftjoin('StoreProducts', function ($join){
                        $join->on('StoreProducts.store_id', '=', 'stores.id');
                    })->leftjoin('products', function ($join) {
                        $join->on('products.id','=','StoreProducts.product_id');
                })
                ->where('products.brand_id', '=', $brandID)
                ->isActive()
                ->get();
```

This is returning a product value, But I wanted it to return all the stores the original table back if the `products.brand_id` was equal to the `$brandID` then return the current store and repeat for all stores.

Hope that makes sense
Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you want the stores which contains a brand?

Comment: I want to filter out the stores with a specific brand, but to find out if the store has the specific brand of product I have to go through two tables and match ids. The store table does not contain a brand_id it has a store_id, the StoreProducts has a store_id and product_id and the product table has a id and brand_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your relations goes like this:

```
Stores -> (n*n)StoreProducts -> Products -> (n*1)Brands
```

which `StoreProducts` is a joining table between `Stores` and `Products`. With this assumption, I would use something like this:

In the `Store` model,

```
public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Product::class, "store_products"); 
}
```

In the `Products` model,

```
public function stores(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Store::class, "store_products");
}
```

In the `StoreProducts` model,

```
public function store(){
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Store::class);
}

public function product(){
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Product::class);
}
```

This way the relationship is created. Then you can use something like this:

```
$stores = \App\Store::whereHas("products", function($q) use ($brandId){
    return $q->where("brand_id", $brandId);
});
```

This will give you the stores which the brand exists.